# How can the cdt7.0 content assist be configured to support handling of enums like structs?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, content-assist

I'm using eclipse helios cdt7.0. The content assist works regarding e.g. structs but in case of enums, the full project index (functions, all kind of enums, etc.) is proposed instead of proposing the valid values of the focused enum.

example:

typedef enum {
 OFF = 0;
 ON
}t_state;

t_state sys_state = <==== Invokation of content assist at this position

==> full index is displayed instead of OFF/ON

The index seems ok: the typedef of the enum and its members are indexed and are hyperlinked. Is there any way to influence this behaviour in the cdt configuration or in the way the code assist should be invoked ?

I understand, that the assignment or comparison of vars of type enum might be a not trivial to be supported by the content assist, but perhaps there is some way to improve the daily work.

Thanks